# Entity Framework Stored Procedure Issues with Entity Framework 6

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I just updated my existing code from Entity framework 5 to 6 and I am getting below error

> {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException: An error was
>   reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be
>   determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database
>   server. See the inner exception and
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this
>   transaction.

My code is working fine in Entity framework 5 but not in 6.

> ((IObjectContextAdapter)SoInDBContext.Instance).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SomeFunction",
>   idParameter, fbIdParameter, emailParameter);

I am not using any transaction in the SP.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266295/net-entity-framework-and-transactions

Comment: yes... i have checked this link... I am not using a global context. And same code is working fine for entity framework 5.

Comment: Are you doing any sort of multithreading?

Comment: no.. I simple insert in the DB