# Simple Injector: Registering open generic type with constructor parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have created a generic type

`public interface IContext<T> {}`

And, I have a type implemented that (with a constructor with parameters)

`public class Context<T> : IContext<T>
{
   public Context(string url, string key)
   {
   }
   ...
}`

I want to register with simple injector. With the below code, I dont know how to pass the values for the constructor

`container.Register(typeof(IContext<>), typeof(Context<>))`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329104/3355392) one shows a way if I have a type passed in the constructor parameter. However, for me its primitive types only. Looks like by overriding construction resolution behaviour I may achieve this. But, dont really get the idea of how shall I leverage it. Can someone guide me to find an appropriate way to register this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with primitive dependencies into an open-generic registration, the typical solution is to extract the set of configuration value(s) into a DTO and inject that DTO into the type's constructor; this allows you to register that new configuration object as singleton into the container:

I have created a generic type

public interface IContext {}

And, I have a type implemented that (with a constructor with parameters)

```
public class ContextConfiguration
{
    public readonly string Url;
    public readonly string Key;
    public ContextConfiguration(string url, string key) { ... }
}

public class Context<T> : IContext<T>
{
    public Context(ContextConfiguration config)
    {
    }
    ...
}

// Configuration
container.RegisterSingleton(new ContextConfiguration(...));
container.Register(typeof(IContext<>), typeof(Context<>));
```

In case you can't change the constructor of that type, you create a sub class of that type that you place inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This sub type again uses this configuration DTO:

```
// Part of the Composition Root
private class ContextConfiguration
{
    public readonly string Url;
    public readonly string Key;
    public ContextConfiguration(string url, string key) { ... }
}

private class CompositionRootContext<T> : Context<T>
{
    public Context(ContextConfiguration config) : base(config.Url, config.Key)
    {
    }
    ...
}

// Configuration
container.RegisterSingleton(new ContextConfiguration(...));
container.Register(typeof(IContext<>), typeof(CompositionRootContext<>));
```

If that `Context<T>` is sealed, you could override the [parameter injection behavior](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-parameter-injection-behavior), but in general, in that case you are dealing with a type that is defined by an external library. For external types it is generally better to hide them behind an application-tailored abstraction (according to the [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)). Instead of letting application code depend on `IContext<T>`, you let the application depend on an interface that is defined by the application. As part of your Composition Root, you would implement an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that adapts the application-specific interface to `Context<T>`. The constructor of that adapter would -again- be able to use this configuration DTO.

Comment: Thanks for the insights Steven. I think I can create a DTO as suggested by you. However, why would I register it as singleton? Cant I pass parameters during runtime? (My requirement also is to pass them during runtime)

Comment: @AthiS: Ah, that was some crucial information missing from your question. The values are _runtime _data_. Please read [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). It describes how to handle runtime data.

Comment: Interesting read Steven. With your inputs I have changed the design so that run time data wont get passed thru the constructor