# One EF Core DbContext Multiple Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

How can I use one DbContext with multiple application?

I have a WCF application (Net TCP binding) interface and implementation works fine with the DbContext. There is a need for API from the same application and I don't want to enable Http Binding on the WCF because of configuration and I have so many contracts. so I decided to import the service into asp.net core 2 via DI it works fine but works connect to Db via DbContext always returning null.

DB Context:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options){}

    public AppDbContext()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            }           
        }
    }
```

Service implementation

```
public partial class GeneralService : IGeneralService, IDisposable
{

    protected readonly AppDbContext Db = new AppDbContext();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Asp.net core Start Up

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        const string connection = @"Server=.\;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));  

        services.AddSingleton<IGeneralService,GeneralService>();
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver());

    }
```

what am I doing wrong, what can I do I really don't want to use Proxy

Answer (score 0):

> connect to Db via DbContext always returning null.

I think that might be down to the fact that you're creating the DB context directly in the service class. You can/should inject your `DbContext` into your service instead. Something like:

```
public partial class GeneralService : IGeneralService, IDisposable
{
   protected readonly AppDbContext Db;

   public GeneralService(AppDbContext db)
   {
       Db = db;
   }
   // ... etc...
}
```

Further, since you're providing a connection string to the db in your `Startup.cs` you don't need the `OnConfiguring` method in your db context.

Finally, services shouldn't be singletons if they're using EF. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153748/singleton-scope-for-efs-dbcontext) which recommends the Request scope.

Comment: This will break the WCF Application

Comment: which part? singletons, or injection?