# C# Dependency Injection : Injecting multiple interfaces into other services

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'd like to inject a number of interfaces to another service.
Let's take a look at 2 services that I want to have their dependency injected.

Inside Term.cs

```
private readonly IWSConfig WSConfig;
private readonly IMemoryCache MemCache;

public Term(IWSConfig wsConfig, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    WSConfig = wsConfig;
    MemCache = memoryCache;
}


public async Task LoadData()
{
    List<ConfigTerm> configTerm = await WSConfig.GetData(); // This is a web service call
    ...
}
```

Inside Person.cs

```
private readonly PersonRepo PersonRepository;
private readonly IMemoryCache MemCache;
private readonly ITerm Term;
private readonly IWSLoadLeave LoadLeave;
private readonly IWSLoadPartics LoadPartics;

public Person(PersonRepo personRepository, IMemoryCache memCache, ITerm term, IWSLoadLeave loadLeave, IWSLoadPartics loadPartics)
{
    PersonRepository = personRepository;
    MemCache = memCache;
    Term = term;
    LoadLeave = loadLeave;
    LoadPartics = loadPartics;
}
```

Code in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(opts => opts.UseOracle(RegistryReader.GetRegistryValue(RegHive.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Configuration["AppSettings:RegPath"], "DB.ConnectionString", RegWindowsBit.Win64)));
services.AddTransient<ILogging<ServiceLog>, ServiceLogRepo>();
services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();    
services.AddHttpClient<IWSConfig, WSConfig>();
services.AddHttpClient<IWSLoadLeave, WSLoadLeave>();
services.AddHttpClient<IWSLoadPartics, WSLoadPartics>();

var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>(); // Can we omit this one and just use the one in AddDbContext?
optionsBuilder.UseOracle(RegistryReader.GetRegistryValue(RegHive.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Configuration["AppSettings:RegPath"], "DB.ConnectionString", RegWindowsBit.Win64));

services.AddSingleton<ITerm, Term>((ctx) => {
    WSConfig wsConfig = new WSConfig(new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(), new ServiceLogRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options))); // Can we change this to the IWSConfig and the ILogging<ServiceLog>
    IMemoryCache memoryCache = ctx.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
    return new Term(wsConfig, memoryCache);
});
services.AddSingleton<IPerson, Person>((ctx) => {
    PersonRepo personRepo = new PersonRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options)); // Can we change this?
    IMemoryCache memoryCache = ctx.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
    ITerm term = ctx.GetService<ITerm>();
    WSLoadLeave loadLeave = new WSLoadLeave(new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(), new ServiceLogRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options))); // Can we change this?
    WSLoadPartics loadPartics = new WSLoadPartics(new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(), new ServiceLogRepo(new DBContext(optionsBuilder.Options))); // Can we change this?
    return new Person(personRepo, memoryCache, term, loadLeave, loadPartics);
});
```

But there are some duplication here and there. I've marked as the comments in the code above.
How to correct it ?

[UPDATE 1]:
If I change the declaration from singleton with the following:

```
services.AddScoped<ITerm, Term>();
services.AddScoped<IPerson, Person>();
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to insert a record using the DbContext.

> {System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A
>   common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
>   from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
>   context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
>   are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
>   using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
>   the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
>   instances. Object name: 'DBContext'.

In my `WSConfig`, it will inherit a base class. This base class also have reference to the ServiceLogRepo, which will call the DbContext to insert a record to the database

In WSConfig

```
public class WSConfig : WSBase, IWSConfig
{
    private HttpClient WSHttpClient;

    public WSConfig(HttpClient httpClient, ILogging<ServiceLog> serviceLog) : base(serviceLog)
    {
        WSHttpClient = httpClient;

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

The WSBase class:

```
public class WSBase : WSCall
{    
    private readonly ILogging<ServiceLog> ServiceLog;

    public WSBase(ILogging<ServiceLog> serviceLog) : base(serviceLog)
    {

    }

    ...
}
```

The WSCall class:

```
public class WSCall 
{
    private readonly ILogging<ServiceLog> ServiceLog;

    public WSCall(ILogging<ServiceLog> serviceLog)
    {
        ServiceLog = serviceLog;
    }
    ....
}
```

And the ServiceLogRepo code

```
public class ServiceLogRepo : ILogging<ServiceLog>
{
    private readonly DBContext _context;

    public ServiceLogRepo(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> LogRequest(ServiceLog apiLogItem)
    {
        await _context.ServiceLogs.AddAsync(apiLogItem);
        int i = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return await Task.Run(() => true);
    }
}
```

I also have the following in Startup.cs to do the web service call upon application load.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ITerm term)
{
    ....
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await term.LoadData());
}
```

It seems when going into term.LoadData(), the DBContext is disposed already.

Comment: Why not just replace your `new DBContext()` with `ctx.GetService< NSWSDBContext >()`?

Comment: Did that, but it gets `Cannot resolve scoped service 'Prj.Entity.DBContext' from root provider.'`. Btw I've fixed the typo, the type name is DBContext.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply register `ITerm` like so?: `services.AddSingleton<ITerm, Term>()` - Assuming `Term` accepts an `IWSConfig`, it should just resolve it from the container. This seems very similar to your last question, and seems to have the same solution.

Comment: @John I get the following error if I change like that:

`InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'Prj.Log.Interfaces.ILogging`1[Prj.Entity.ServiceLog]' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Prj.Entity.DBContext'.`
...
`Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Prj.WebAPI.Helpers.Interfaces.ITerm' for the parameter 'term' of method 'Configure' on type 'Prj.Startup'.`
...

Comment: So your problem is that you registered DB Context scoped in a web app, and then you're trying to inject it as singleton. a) of course it won't work b) instead of injecting the db context to singleton, inject a factory. resolve a singleton in the operation and dispose at the end. Otherwise it is likely you will have a db connection for the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Based on singleton DbContext being bad (according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153748/singleton-scope-for-efs-dbcontext)), and not being able to use a scoped service in a singleton, I'd suggest rethinking your approach. Do `Term` and `Person` need to be singleton?

Comment: I used singleton for ITerm and IPerson, due to I want to have only one httpclient for the lifetime of the app. If I create using scoped, then it will create multiple httpclients.  HttpClient is more suitable to be used in singleton.

Comment: Forget `HttpClient`. The whole HttpClientFactory stuff (which you're using!) was designed to deal with the old issues. Multiple `HttpClient` instances are not the problem, but multiple `HttpClientHandler` instances _are_. HttpClientFactory handles these for you. Read [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [this](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) (which covers both why singleton HttpClient is bad, and how HttpClientFactory helps)

Comment: @rcs if using AddHttpClient then that is being managed for you already

Comment: I've updated my question, but I encounter another error when trying to use the ServiceLog to insert a record to the database.

Comment: @Nkosi, the WSCall is being inherited by WSConfig, I've updated the code.

Comment: Did you follow the instruction of the exception message about how to deal with DbContext?

Comment: @Nkosi There is no Dispose call. I wonder how it gets disposed. If you see, when I try to run `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await term.LoadData());`. The DbContext is disposed already.

Comment: Because it is not awaited, it is being disposed before you are finished with the db context

Comment: Where does the term used in startup come from?

Comment: @Nkosi, the function is called in the `Configure` function, which will be called after all the declaration of services completed.

Comment: Don't use `Task.Run` like you are. Even if this was in the context of a web request, you can't run code in another task (fire and forget) and expect it to work like that. You and a friend walk into a shop. You given them a hammer so they can hit some nails in the floor of the shop. Its a funny hammer though - it explodes when you leave the shop (it is _scoped_ to your presence in the shop). What do you think will happen if they stay in the shop and start hammering nails in **and you leave without them**?

Comment: Ur Person class takes Personrepository as parameter. This is very bad design. Ur person repo should be taking person as parameter instead.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want to call `term.LoadData` from `Configure` / `Startup`?

Comment: @mjwills Because I want to pre-load some data from a web service call. The call may take some time, so when the app starts, I want it running in the background, so when user comes in, they will see the data is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First properly register all the necessary dependencies in `ConfigureServices` using the appropriate liftetime scopes

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(opts => opts.UseOracle(RegistryReader.GetRegistryValue(RegHive.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Configuration["AppSettings:RegPath"], "DB.ConnectionString", RegWindowsBit.Win64)));
services.AddTransient<ILogging<ServiceLog>, ServiceLogRepo>();
services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();    
services.AddHttpClient<IWSConfig, WSConfig>();
services.AddHttpClient<IWSLoadLeave, WSLoadLeave>();
services.AddHttpClient<IWSLoadPartics, WSLoadPartics>();

services.AddScoped<ITerm, Term>();
services.AddScoped<IPerson, Person>();
```

Given the async nature of the method being called in `Configure` the `DbContext` is being disposed before you are done with it.

Now ideally given what you are trying to achieve you should be using a background service `IHostedServive` which will be started upon startup of the application.

```
public class TermHostedService : BackgroundService {
    private readonly ILogger<TermHostedService> _logger;

    public TermHostedService(IServiceProvider services, 
        ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger) {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
        _logger.LogInformation("Term Hosted Service running.");

        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope()) {
            var term = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITerm>();    
            await term.LoadData();
            _logger.LogInformation("Data Loaded.");
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
        _logger.LogInformation("Term Hosted Service is stopping.");    
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

when registered at startup

```
services.AddHostedService<TermHostedService>();
```

Reference [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services)