# ASP.NET Core - Update 1 Element of a cached List<Element> in IMemoryCache using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm building a webshop using `ASP.Net Core` (Razor Pages) with `EF Core`. To speed up a lot of calculation, I cache all the products (~100.000). The information is coming from our db.

### Models

```
class ProductInformation{
    // some information about how to display a product
    public string productnumber {get; set;}
    public Product product {get; set;}
}

class Product{
    public string productnumber {get; set;}
    public decimal price {get; set;}
    public Category category {get; set}
    // and a lot more...
}
```

In my DBContext I define that every PoductInformation **has exact one** Product.

### The caching method

```
private readonly IMemoryCache _cache; // is set in the constructor
private readonly DBContext _dbContext; // is set in the constructor
public List<ProductInformation> GetProductInformationList(){
    List<ProductInformation> = _cache.GetOrCreate("ProductInformations", entry =>
    {
        entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        List<ProductInformation> list =_dbContext.ProductInformation.ToList();
        // do a lot of calculations on the list-elements
        return list;
    });
}
```

The whole caching method takes 100-120 seconds. Now another system updates my price in the DB for one product and of course I want to show the correct price of that product on my webshop. Let's assume I want to check the price every 15 minutes.

### Solutions - tried but not satisfying

**Method 1**

I can set caching of the whole list to 15 minutes, that will work, but it's not what I want. Refreshing the whole cache is slow and not necessary. 99.9% of the data has not changed.

**Method 2**

Inside my model ProductInformation I make a method that updates the Product:

```
class ProductInformation{
    // some information about how to display a product
    public string productnumber {get; set;}
    public Product product {get; set;}

    pubic DateTime ProductTimeStamp {get; set;}
    public UpdateProduct(){
        // If ProductTimeStamp is more than 15 minutes in the past
        // get Product from the DB
        // and update the timestamp
    }
}
```

Everywhere I display a ProductInformation, I call `UpdateProduct()`. Then I only re-check the 'old' prices from products that I display. This is much more efficiënt than recalculate the whole cache. But now I need a DB connection inside my ProductInformation (that is cached). I can't get this to work.

**Method 3**

Since the problem in method 2 is that I don't have a DB connection, I can take the `UpdateProduct()` method outside the model and put it in my repository where I have a DB connection. Everywhere I display a ProdctInformation, I need to call something like `_proudctRepository.UpdateProduct(ref ProductInformation);`. This method looks like:

```
public void UpdateProduct(ref ProductInformation pi){
    pi.Product = _dbContext.Product.Where(p => p.productnumber == pi.productnumber);
   // Of course I also need to do the calculations from the caching-method in GetProductInformationList()
}
```

But this feels not right. The Entity Framework has organized for me the connection between ProductInformation and Product, is it then possible to redefine Product this way? I think its not the way to go.

### Question

I think a lot of people use IMemoryCaching for equal situations (where you want to update just a single element in a cached List or just some elements (price / stock / ...) of a cached list element). How can we handle this?

Comment: If you know when an object changes you just have to call a method afterwards.
MyCacheManager.UpdateProduct(DbContext myContext, ProductInformation pi) { ... update cache ...}

Comment: True. But I don't know when a Product has changed. And then the question of method 3: is it possible to update a cached item this way? Does it affect my 'Entity Framework relation''?

Comment: if you dont know when an item has changed, then a cache is probably the wrong solution. Or you have to write some query, set some [LastUpdatedOn] flags on your db records. You Should set a different key for every product tho. so if you have 1m products, you should have 1m cache keys, and then you can also easily delete / update the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add `LastChanged` (datetime[offset]) column to your `Product` database and ask "another system" update it too when it updates your price. With this, you can easily save `Max(LastChanged)` in your cache and query only for changed Products, reducing time and size of updates, and you can do it more frequently.

2) Add [AsNoTracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries) when putting data into cache. You will not update them back to DB (I guess), so no-tracking will speed up everything a little. Also, this will give you no-worry about `ProductInformation` - `Product` EF relations, because EF will not be tracking them anyway and `pi.Product` will be a usual object-holding property without any hidden magic.

3) It's not good to check for price updates on every page render. Updates should run in other thread / background. Setup some background task that will check for updated prices and reload updated objects into cache - with (1) you can run updates every 5 minutes or less. Check here [DbContext for background tasks via Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109234/dbcontext-for-background-tasks-via-dependency-injection) for obtaining DbContext.

Comment: Scheduled task works and getting the Products that needs to be updated goed right. But then it looks like I can't update the cached List with some kind of: `GetProductInformationList().FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.ProductNumber == newProductInformation.ProductNumber).Product = newProductInformation.Product ;`. What is the correct way to do this? Do I need to create a cache-entry for every 'ProductInformation'?

Comment: Excuse me, my testing-procedure wasn't right: the above method works! Thanks a lot!