# Cannot access a disposed object in Task.Run

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am using **.NET Core 3.1**. I want to run some background processing without user having to wait for it to finish (it takes about 1 minute). Therefore, I used `Task.Run` like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(...)
    {
        await _myService.CreatePostAsync(...);
        return View();
    }
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyService(MyDbContext dbContext, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task CreatePostAsync(Post post)
    {
        ...
        string username = GetUsername();
        DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> dbOptions = GetDbOptions();
        Task.Run(() => SaveFiles(username, dbOptions, _scopeFactory));
    }

    private void SaveFiles(string username, DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> dbOptions, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var otherService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOtherService>();
            var cntxt = new MyDbContext(dbOptions, username);

            Post post = new Post("abc", username);

            cntxt.Post.Add(post); <----- EXCEPTION

            cntxt.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I recieve the following exception in marked line:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.'
```

Why does this happen? I used custom constructor (and not `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>()`) for MyDbContext because I need to save one additional propery (username) for later use in overriden methods.

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    private string _username;
    private readonly DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> _options;

    public DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> DbOptions { get { return _options; } }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, string username) : base(options)
    {
        _username = username;
        _options = options;
    }

    ... other overriden methods
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `MyService` usage ? Is it created in the controller? Asp.Net creates new container scope for each incoming request. It means that container from the scope is disposed when controller's method returns the result. This explains the `IServiceProvider disposed` error you have. This may cause ctor object instances to be disposed by the container while certain task continues to use those instances.

Comment: Yes, `MyService` is injected in the controller constructor. Controller then calls `await _myService.CreatePostAsync(...)`. What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: I updated the question so that it includes controller part as well.

Comment: You should pretty much never use `Task.Run` in a web app. There is no point. It allows the current thread to be returned to the pool, but simply pulls out another in its place from that same pool. Since all requests are serviced from that same threadpool, all you're doing is cutting your total available request throughput.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, don't hide a thread-pool operation away in your service; let the calling coded decide whether to run the operation on the thread-pool or not:

As you are using dependency injection, the framework is disposing your `DbContext` at the end of the HTTP request.

You need to inject your service scope factory into your controller, and request the service from there:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyController(IMyService myService, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(...)
    {
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(SaveInBackground);
        return View();
    }

    private async Task SaveInBackground(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
            await scopedService.CreatePostAsync(...);
        }
    }
}
```

`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` works in a similar way to `Task.Run`, except it ensures that the app doesn't shut down until all background work items have completed.

Your service would need to be something like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public MyService(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task CreatePostAsync(Post post)
    {
        _dbContext.Post.Add(post);

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To pass additional parameters to `SaveInBackground`:

```
private async Task SaveInBackground(YourParam param)
```

Then call like:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken => SaveInBackground(yourParam));
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I pass additional parameter to `SaveInBackground` (ex. model which I want to save to database)?

Comment: `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is not available in .NET Core 3. What should I use instead?

Answer (score -2):

You shoud create a Service with a Singleton lifecycle and inject a DBContext inside and queue all tasks inside

Comment: Injecting a scoped dependency (such as a `DbContext`) into a singleton is in general a bad idea. If you think that it is a good approach in *this particular* case, you should explain why that is, and why you won't run into [concurrency (and other) issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266295/net-entity-framework-and-transactions/3266481#3266481).

Comment: I'm okay with the fact that a global DBContext is a terrible idea, that why i suggest to queue tasks to avoid the concurency issue

Comment: There are other issues with global DbContext instances besides concurrency, such as that their data becomes stale (as noted in the referenced answer). And you might be fine with all this, but in the very least you should warn the inattentive or less experienced reader of your answer about this.