# How do I configure Autofac so my DbContext is created each time new?

Tags: c#, winforms, autofac, dbcontext

I am new to Autofac. In my `program.cs` file I have my registrations:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterLogger();
builder.RegisterType<GetUserFactory>().As<IGetUser>();
builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<LoginForm>();
builder.RegisterType<RegisterForm>();
builder.RegisterType<MainFormView>().As<IMainFormView>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<MainFormPresenter>();
builder.RegisterType<TestForm>();
builder.RegisterType<PeopleReport>();
Container = builder.Build();
```

When I open my `MainFormView` it works fine the first time. But any attempt to open it a second time or any subsequent attempt states my `MyContext` is disposed.

```
using (var mainFormView = Program.Container.Resolve<IMainFormView>())
{
    mainFormView.SetTag(Program.Container.Resolve<MainFormPresenter>());

    var form = (MainFormView)mainFormView;

    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

My question is how should I configure `Autofac` so my `MyContext` is new-ed up for each `MainFormView` request?

**UPDATE:**

After looking more closely at my error message I see it is my `MainFormView` that is being disposed that is the reason for the error message not the `MyContext`.

Comment: Use per-dependency scope: _a unique instance will be returned from each request for a service._ `builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().InstancePerDependency();` This is a default option, so you can simply skip last method: `builder.RegisterType<MyContext>()`

Comment: @Fabio I set my `builder.RegisterType<MyContext>()` to a per-dependency scope. I still have the same error that my context has been disposed.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've got:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyContext>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Database contexts should generally not be declared to have a lifetime scope. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why/) and [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266295/net-entity-framework-and-transactions/)