# Why thread safe DbContext for only Read operations is not possible?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I know that DbContext is not thread safe.
My question is, Why thread safe DbContext for **only Read operations** is not possible?
Except change tracker what causes DbContext not to be thread safe?

Can you explain why 'ReadOnlyDbContext' is not possible?

Comment: Because designing things that store state in a thread-safe way is hard, and because its dependency injection in this case is relatively cheap. The real question is why you want this.

Comment: `Read-only operations` doesn't need to be thread-safe, the concept of thread-safe mainly discusses write action, because, the regarding action change the data not reading data.

Comment: The Q is not clear. `ReadOnlyDbContext` relation to thread-safe

Comment: @AFarmanbar a DbContext keeps quite some internal state while executing a query and materializing the results, even for SELECT queries.

Comment: @CodeCaster, ef core internal state as you mentioned, is definitely handled by ef core so there is not any concern for thread safety as it is safe. so read operations are thread-safe by default but write operations are not thread-safe and the developer should take care of that either in the state manager and so on.

Comment: @AFarmanbar no, that's simply not true. Two concurrent read operations will definitely corrupt a DbContext and/or make it throw. Something being "internal" (i.e. hidden from the developer) does not make something automagically thread-safe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ok to inject DbContext as singleton when there is only read operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64568030/is-it-ok-to-inject-dbcontext-as-singleton-when-there-is-only-read-operations)

Comment: @CodeCaster, wow, really ... that's a really surprising fact