# Dependency injection to include post-construction actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

In our solution, we use dependency injection to instantiate instances of a `DbContext` class which many other services depend on:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<OurAppDbContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
// ... A bunch of services that take a new OurAppDbContext as an argument
```

This successfully results in instantiating a dozen or so services with their own `OurAppDbContext` instances.

**The Problem**

The `OurAppDbContext` constructor (auto-generated by EntityFramework, therefore not editable) is not quite sufficient for our purposes. If we had it our way, every instance would be constructed as such:

```
OurAppDbContext newDbContext = new OurAppDbContext();
newDbContext.Database.Log += log => Debug.WriteLine(log);
return newDbContext;
```

Right now, the way we can hook this event is in every constructor of every service that gets one of these instances. e.g.:

```cs
public class AdminDataRepository : IAdminDataRepository
{
    private readonly OurAppDbContext _dbContext;
    public AdminDataRepository(OurAppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbContext.Database.Log += log => Debug.WriteLine(log);
        ...
```

But we would rather not have this code copy-pasted into 10+ different service constructors as it becomes a maintenance headache, we might miss it in a few places, or they might get out of sync, etc.

Is there a way to instruct the dependency injector to do this to each `OurAppDbContext` it constructs - before it passes it along to whatever service it's constructing that depends on it?

Comment: Please be warned that the use of the [PerThreadLifetimeManager](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.Lifetime.PerThreadLifetimeManager.html) is typically a bad idea when running in a web application, especially when your code is asynchronous. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266481/264697). I'm not that familiar with Unity, but using the `PerRequestLifetimeManager` is probably better.

Comment: @Steven that's a huge tip,  thanks. I'm very new to this project, and there are lots of cobwebs to clear out. I suspect this is responsible for a chunk of them. Please feel free to edit your answer below to PerRequestLifetimeManager, in case some poor future soul copy-pastes blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the registration using a factory delegate:

```cs
container.RegisterFactory<OurAppDbContext>(c =>
    {
        OurAppDbContext newDbContext = new OurAppDbContext();
        newDbContext.Database.Log += log => Debug.WriteLine(log);
        return newDbContext;
    },
    new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution occurred to me, turns out it works!

We can create our own `DBContext` class derived from the EF auto-generated one:

```cs
public class LoggingOurAppDbContext : OurAppDbContext
{
    public LoggingOurAppDbContext() : base()
    {
        this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

And instruct Unity (dependency injection) to create instances of these rather than instances of the EF-generated one.

It should "just work" - without even editing the constructor arguments of all the services that depend on a PortfolioAccumulationDbContext instance - because inheritance makes the two types interchangeable.

I'm familiar with the syntax for providing a concrete type to implement an interface wherever it's required as a dependency:

```cs
container.RegisterType<ISomeInterface, SomeConcreteType>();
```

But I wasn't sure it would work in my case since the base `OurAppDbContext` auto-generated by entity framework does not implement any kind of interface, all services that require one are expecting an instance of the concrete type `OurAppDbContext`. It turns out the same syntax can be used to provide a more-derived type to satisfy an already-concrete type argument:

```cs
container.RegisterType<OurAppDbContext, LoggingOurAppDbContext>(...);
```

Problem solved.

Comment: i was about to suggest the same thing. personally, i'd just register a custom Factory for the base class that produces an instance of a the derived class. (but maybe ask the follow-up question as a separate SO-question?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with providing factories to unity, but I did test the above attempt to override a concrete type with a more-derived type (`container.RegisterType<OurAppDbContext, LoggingOurAppDbContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());`) and was surprised to see that it works! Not sure why I thought it wouldn't, I guess I've just never seen it done before.